# Which BSD best suited to run as VMware guest?

Tags: freebsd, vmware-vsphere, openbsd, bsd, netbsd

I want to deploy a VM to serve DNS and files (via NFS) to other *nix systems in my infrastructure.

Due to reasons beyond my control, I *need* a very light OS, so I naturally choose the *BSD family.

Can you recommend which *BSD is the best VMware guest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well vSphere 4.x only supports FreeBSD 6.x-8.x while vSphere 5.x also supports Mac OSX 10.6-10.7 - so one of those, anything else isn't supported.

Comment: Might have luck with NanoBSD; it's built off of BSD 8.0 and is what pfSense uses.

Comment: @Chopper3 hmmm... yes, you seem to be right. I guess I'll fire up FreeBSD and see what I'll get. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From practical experience I can tell you all of the Big 3 BSDs (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD) will run in VMWare, **but** as Chopper3 said, only FreeBSD and Apple's OS X (Mach/BSD Hybrid) are officially supported by VMWare.

If this is going to be a production system and support from the VMWare folks is important to you I would stick to a stripped-down version FreeBSD -- If you only start the services you need and zealously defend against feature creep it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, support is something I must not overlook. @Chopper3 answered first so the checkmark still belongs to him/her, but I'll upvote your answer :)